# XML Schema -elements with restrictions(maxLenght) and Mandatory values

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I'm supposed to create a XML Schema for this.

Where column A is Tag Name column  B is Data Type column  C is Max length  and column  D is Mandatory

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:complexType name="Applicant">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Surname" >
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="26" />
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="FirstName">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="26" />
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>

        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>


//etc..
</xsd:schema>
```

And this is what I've tried yet.

But my problem is I'm not able to give `Mandatory` for complex type `Applicant` and `element names`(Surname,First name) because `required` is not available for elements.
But it is available for attributes.

Plz Feel free to edit and comment for any clarifications

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` of a element is `1`.

So, by default, each element has to appear, if you don't define those parameters.

Comment: I agree but can we have any restrictions for complextType?

Comment: No, you can't. Your `complexType` is going to be used by something. For example, you can say that you have a element `A` and it's type is `Applicant`. By default, `A` has to appear 1 time in the xml. But the `complexType` has nothing to do with it. You can eventually have another element `B` with `Applicant` type and so on...

Answer (score -2):

I'm not shure, but i have tested with success this xsd

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="rootelement">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="optional_element" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="26"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="required_element" minOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="26"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="optional_complex_type" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="ct_1">
                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                        <xsd:maxLength value="26"/>
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                </xsd:simpleType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="required_complex_type" minOccurs="1">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="ct_1">
                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                        <xsd:maxLength value="26"/>
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                </xsd:simpleType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: For element, length i have already given in maxLenght.
I want to put madatory for fields(lement name="FirstName")as we have for attributes i.e use="required"

Comment: This is the same as `<xsd:element name="FirstName">` since the default value of `minOccurs`is already 1.

Comment: @bdn02 After your edit: on the required elements, you still don't need to define `minOccurs` to 1. That's the default value, so they will be "required" if you don't set anything at all. Also, you're not setting a `complexType` required, but a `element`, that actually is a `complexType` (and not what OP asked). Different things.